# Android arduino communication via usb using adk mode

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I am working on android and arduino application which uses adk mode communication I have implemented runnable in my main activity and in run method of this I am reading values and when reading finishes I am writing values to arduino board and communication is running infinite.I am using handler for updating GUI but application stops it's communication after sometime I am not able to figure out what is the problem? does GUI update in handler takes more time so that it is happening or anything else?

Following code is for receiving and sending data:

```
 while (true) { // read data
    try {
    int ret_read = 0;
    byte[] buffer_read = new byte[128];
    ret_read = mInputStream.read(buffer_read);

    for (int p = 0; p < 2 * (noOfFSensors); p = p + 2) {
    intListValues.add((int) composeInt(buffer_read[p],
                buffer_read[p + 1]));

    Log.d("Jankari", "Pu Value : "+String.valueOf((int) composeInt(buffer_read[p],
                buffer_read[p + 1])));

    }


      Message mPu = Message.obtain(mHandlerPuSensors);
      mPu.obj = new ValueMsgPuSensors("f", ret_read,intListFValues);
        mHandlerPuSensors.sendMessage(mPu);

    for (int a = 0; a < 2 * (noOfAnSensors); a = a + 2) {
    intListAnValues.add((int) (composeInt(buffer_read[2* (noOfFSensors) + a], 
                buffer_read[2* (noOfFSensors) + a + 1])));
    Log.d("Jankari", "An Value : "+String.valueOf(
         (int) (composeInt(buffer_read[2* (noOfFSensors) + a], 
    buffer_read[2* (noOfFSensors) + a + 1]))));

    }
    Message mAn = Message.obtain(mHandlerAnSensors);
    mAn.obj = new ValueMsgAnSensors("f", ret_read,
    intListAnValues);
    mHandlerAnSensors.sendMessage(mAn);

    for (int l = 0; l < noOfSw; l++) {
    intListSwValues.add((int) buffer_read[2* (noOfFSensors) +
        2 * (noOfAnSensors) + l]);
    Log.d("Jankari", "Sw : "+String.valueOf((int)
          buffer_read[2* (noOfFSensors) + 2 * (noOfAnSensors) + l]) );
    }
    Message mSw = Message.obtain(mHandlerSwSensors);
    mSw.obj = new ValueMsgSwSensors("f", ret_read,intListSwValues);
    mHandlerSwSensors.sendMessage(mSw);

        i += 1;


    mInputStream.close();

    // Send Output to arduino
    sendoutput();
       } catch (IOException e) {
      break;
    }

}
```

And handlers that I am using are,

```
Handler mHandlerPuSensors = new Handler() {    
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ValueMsgPuSensors msgPu = (ValueMsgPuSensors) msg.obj;
        txtReceivedBytes.setText("Received Bytes: " + msgPu.getRet());
        for (int i = 0; i < txtListFSensors.size(); i++) {
            txtListFSensors.get(i).setText(String.valueOf(msgPu.getFReadings().get(i)));
        }
        intListFValues.clear();         
    }
};
```

Comment: Share your Arduino code and also is your Arduino board getting reseted, when the communication stops?

Comment: No arduino board is not getting reset

Comment: Hi,Sudar I have 21 sensors and I want to show each sensors data at a time I have used handler for updating data but after some time my application communication stops without any error in logcat

Comment: There are two possibilities. Either Arduino is getting reset or Android is getting into a deadlock.

Comment: Arduino board is running I have pasted portion of code of android application.